# How to unsubscribe from Check/Uncheck event of datagridcheckbox column in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, wpfdatagrid

I subscribed to the Check/Uncheck event via cell style, like below.

```
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  x:Name="colAccept" Binding="{Binding Accepted}" Header="Accepted">
       <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
          <Style>
             <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked_Accepted"/>
             <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnUnchecked_Accepted"/>
          </Style>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

I am updating the property that is bound to this column from the code behind but would not like the event to fire that one time. In winforms, I would unsubscribe from the event, then uncheck the checkbox, and then resubscribe, but how could I do this in WPF xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to use a DataGridTemplateColumn instead.

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Accepted">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Checked="OnChecked_Accepted" Unchecked="OnUnchecked_Accepted" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

in the handler

```
    private void OnUnchecked_Accepted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;
        cb.Unchecked -= OnUnchecked_Accepted;  //this line unsubscribes the event
    }
```

Comment: this solves the problem, but with the use of DataGridTemplateColumn I have problem doing check/uncheck with the the space bar. Accepting this as an answer. Thanks!